# Angular: how show for debug a visual feedback when a component is repaint/rendered?

Tags: angular

I'm searching a simple way for show a visual feedback when a component is repaint/rendered for debugging/developing purpose.

I have made a component for count the re-rendering. Basically the idea is: if the template has a function call, Angular call the function when the template is re-rendered:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'count-rendering',
  template: `<code>Render count: {{ render() }}</code>`,
})
export class CountRenderingComponent {
  private count: number = 0;

  render() {
    this.count++;
    return this.count;
  }
}
```

For debug the number of times a component is re-rendered, just simply put 'count-rendering' component into the component to debug

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `{{name}}<br /><count-rendering></count-rendering>`,
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Online demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3hnhtz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Is my idea correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to acheive, but having a function in your template will not exactly "re-render" a component, it will trigger the change detection mechanism. Is this what you want to monitor ?

In case you might need it, there are lifecycle hooks methods that you can plug in, depending on what you need :

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I want a visual feedback when a component is re-render... ngDoCheck() seem good for that. Thanks